# Why can't I see the weather information in Notification Center?

Tags: ipad, ios, notifications

After upgrading my iPad 4 to iOS 7, I don't see the weather forecast in the new Notification Center. The calendar is there, and the bottom of the Notification Center has the Yahoo! copyright info for the weather data, but the weather information is not displayed.

Wi-fi is turned on, but I have the location services disabled. When turning on location services, the weather info is shown. What's strange is that on my wife's iPad, the weather info is shown even with location services disabled. Both of our iPads are Wi-fi only, no 3G.

Are you seeing the same behavior? What could be causing this inconsistency?

Comment: Sorry Apple, not switching location services on just to watch the weather.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this thread is old, but there are so many issues with iOS7, that there are probably many who still haven't found a solution to this.  What worked for me: Settings > Privacy > Location Services -  Turn on Location Services (if it's not already), and also, scroll down to Weather and make sure that specific app is turned on.  After that, the text weather showed up under the date on Notification Center.  And I have my Weather app in a folder.

iPhone 4S
iOS7

Comment: This worked on iOS 8.2. I wondered where it went, as it used to show in Notifications.

Answer (score 1):

**Restart your iOS device.**

This seems to be a [Heisenberg bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug): I restarted the iOS device after removing a "Weather" folder according to this answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/103131/25260) and I got a weather info to the summary *"Mostly clear currently. It's 2 degrees; the high will be 9 degrees."*

I tested also different settings in Notification Center and the changes requires restart before becoming visible.

It may be that the *"Weather"* folder is just a red-herring here. Anyway test Restart after changing settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading to **iOS 8**, that is, no weather info in the Today summary, except the copyright link at the bottom.

Based on [randy's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117697/91483), I went to Settings > Privacy > Location Services > Weather. I turned the setting off then back on, and went back up in Settings. Now the weather is in Today.

Answer (score 0):

I initially saw the same problem on my iOS 7 iPhone. [Some comments here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130918162742AA4Nsl1) suggest that the problem stems from having the Weather app in a folder. Indeed I did have the Weather app in a folder, also called Weather. I moved the Weather app out of its folder, and renamed that folder from Weather to Meteorology. Shortly thereafter, weather information began appearing in the Notification Center. I put the Weather app back into its original folder, and renamed that folder back to Weather. Weather information continues to appear in the Notification Center.

So now I’m unsure whether this was the real problem or not. Perhaps the weather information server was temporarily overloaded, and this business about folders is a red herring. It’s hard for me to tell.

@nwinkler, do you have the Weather app in a folder? If so, try removing it from that folder to see if it helps. If it seems to help you too, then I guess this was really the issue. If it doesn’t help you, or if your Weather app is not in a folder at all, then probably that wasn’t the root cause in my case either. Either way, please add a comment here to let me (and others) know!

Comment: I don't have the weather app in a folder and I have the same problem as the op so it cannot be because of the folder at least alone -- yet I had a folder named "Weather" that I now renamed to "Metereology" but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Backup before you do any changes so that you can replace it if anything wrong happens.

Browse to `/var/mobile/Library/BulletinBoard/`. Delete `SectionInfo.plist` and respring.

Note: Once you go to safe mode it breaks again but it stays after a reboot.

If you go to safe mode, delete the file again and respring.

It fixes other problems such as Tomorrow view not showing events. I, think it forces your device to rebuild the list and correct the errors.

Answer (score -1):

In Settings > Notification Center, make sure you have the Today View and the Today Summary turned on. You will also need to enable location services for Weather. This applies even for the WiFi-ony iPad (it will obtain location data from the WiFi network).

Comment: -1 this is not the issue at least with me. I have the same problem as the op and I have the settings you describe here but still I cannot see any weather info, just the Yahoo copyright notice. I have tested it now with iPhone 5 iOS7 but the same problem seems to be with iPad mini iOS 7 also.